# Use oracle LAG function data in calculations

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, lag

I want get STOCK and weighted average unit cost `WAUC`.

TABLE T1:

| ROW | ITEM | IN | OUT | PRICE | STOCK | WAUC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1000 | - | 20 | 1000 | 20 |
| 2 | A | 2000 | - | 25 | - | - |
| 3 | A | 1500 | - | 15 | - | - |
| 4 | A | 500 | - | 20 | - | - |

I have the first 5 columns and the first two records of last two columns, and want to get the rest of last two columns `STOCK` and `WAUC`.

```
WAUC = ((PREVIOUS_PRICE * PREVIOUS_STOCK) + (CURRENT_IN * CURRENT_PRICE)) / CURRENT_STOCK
```

So, I write the query:

```
SELECT ROW,
       SUM(IN - OUT) OVER(ORDER BY ROW) STOCK,
       ((LAG(STOCK * WAUC) OVER (ORDER BY ROW)) + (IN * PRICE)) / STOCK AS WAUC
FROM T1
```

What I want is :

| ROW | ITEM | IN | OUT | PRICE | STOCK | WAUC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1000 | - | 20 | 1000 | 20 |
| 2 | A | 2000 | - | 25 | 3000 | 23.33 |
| 3 | A | 1500 | - | 15 | 4500 | 20.55 |
| 4 | A | 500 | - | 20 | 5000 | 20.49 |

In other words, I want to use `LAG` results in calculation data.

Comment: You seem to believe that "lag" means "running" (from first row to current row). That is not what "lag" means.

Comment: NOTE: `ROW` is a reserved word. So are `IN` and `OUT`. Avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula should be:

```
WAUC = (
         PREVIOUS_WAUC * PREVIOUS_STOCK
       + (CURRENT_IN - CURRENT_OUT) * CURRENT_PRICE
       )
       / CURRENT_STOCK
```

---

You can use a `MODEL` clause (with some extra measurements to make the calculation simpler):

```sql
SELECT "ROW", item, "IN", "OUT", price, stock, wauc
FROM   t1
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY ("ROW")
  MEASURES (item, "IN", "OUT", price, 0 AS change, 0 AS stock, 0 AS total, 0 AS wauc)
  RULES (
    change["ROW"] = COALESCE("IN"[cv()], 0) - COALESCE("OUT"[cv()], 0),
    stock["ROW"]  = change[cv()] + COALESCE(stock[cv()-1], 0),
    total["ROW"]  = change[cv()] * price[cv()] + COALESCE(total[cv()-1], 0),
    wauc["ROW"]   = total[cv()] / stock[cv()]
);
```

Or, from Oracle 12, using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT "ROW",
       item,
       "IN",
       "OUT",
       price,
       total_stock AS stock,
       total_cost / total_stock AS wauc
FROM   t1
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY "ROW"
  MEASURES
    SUM(COALESCE("IN", 0) - COALESCE("OUT", 0)) AS total_stock,
    SUM((COALESCE("IN", 0) - COALESCE("OUT", 0))*price) AS total_cost
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (all_rows+)
  DEFINE
    all_rows AS 1 = 1
)
```

Or analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT "ROW",
       item,
       "IN",
       "OUT",
       price,
       SUM(COALESCE("IN",0) - COALESCE("OUT", 0)) OVER (ORDER BY "ROW")
         AS stock,
       SUM((COALESCE("IN",0) - COALESCE("OUT", 0))*price) OVER (ORDER BY "ROW")
        / SUM(COALESCE("IN",0) - COALESCE("OUT", 0)) OVER (ORDER BY "ROW")
        AS wauc
FROM   t1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 ("ROW", ITEM, "IN", "OUT", PRICE, STOCK, WAUC) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 1000, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), 20, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', 2000, NULL, 25, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', 1500, NULL, 15, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A',  500, NULL, 20, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | ROW | ITEM | IN | OUT | PRICE | STOCK | WAUC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A | 1000 |  | 20 | 1000 | 20 |
> | 2 | A | 2000 |  | 25 | 3000 | 23.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 |
> | 3 | A | 1500 |  | 15 | 4500 | 20.55555555555555555555555555555555555556 |
> | 4 | A | 500 |  | 20 | 5000 | 20.5 |

*Note: `ROW`, `IN` and `OUT` are keywords and you should not use them as identifiers as you would have to use quoted identifiers everywhere they occur.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb205069415e6beed302f2a196557e82)*

Comment: lol - changing the "analytic functions" solution (from the original one you offered) is OK, but ... to one that was already posted when you made the change? I expect better.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with "lag".

Using MT0's sample data:

```
select "ROW", item, "IN", "OUT", price,
       sum(nvl("IN", 0) - nvl("OUT", 0)) 
           over (partition by item order by "ROW") as stock,
       round(sum((nvl("IN", 0) - nvl("OUT", 0)) * price)
           over (partition by item order by "ROW") 
       / sum(nvl("IN", 0) - nvl("OUT", 0))
           over (partition by item order by "ROW"), 2 ) as wauc
from   t1
;

   ROW ITEM     IN    OUT  PRICE  STOCK   WAUC
------ ---- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
     1 A      1000            20   1000     20
     2 A      2000            25   3000  23.33
     3 A      1500            15   4500  20.56
     4 A       500            20   5000   20.5
```